# FancyBox 2 Ajax Gallery

Tags: jquery, ajax, gallery, fancybox-2

I have a page that shows avatars of members. When you click an avatar, it will load the profile of that member using FancyBox 2. It works just fine if you click it one by one. But I want it to work like a gallery in fancybox. so that when member click an avatar, he can click next to load the next profile.

Here is my js code. It open member's profile but only shows the profile i click even when i click next or previous. But the fancybox title shows different usernames.

```
$("a.ProfilePreview").click(function() {
a = $(this).attr('data-val');
$("a.ProfilePreview").attr('rel', 'gallery').fancybox({
    fixed: false,
    autoCenter: false,
    scrolling   : 'no',
    href : "http://localhost/site/preview/" + a, 
    type : 'ajax',
    openEffect : 'fade',
    closeEffect : 'fade',
    padding     : 10
});
});
```

Here's my HTML code

```
<div class="image">
<a rel="gallery" href="http://localhost/site/user1/" class="ProfilePreview" data-val="user1" title="user1"><img src="http://localhost/site/media/uploads/photo1.jpg" alt="user1" border="0"></a>
</div>

<div class="image">
<a rel="gallery" href="http://localhost/site/user2/" class="ProfilePreview" data-val="user2" title="user2"><img src="http://localhost/site/media/uploads/photo2.jpg" alt="user2" border="0"></a>
</div>

<div class="image">
<a rel="gallery" href="http://localhost/site/user3/" class="ProfilePreview" data-val="user3" title="user3"><img src="http://localhost/site/media/uploads/photo3.jpg" alt="user3" border="0"></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind I've come up with a solution:

```
$("a.ProfilePreview").click(function() {
    $("a.ProfilePreview").attr('rel', 'gallery').fancybox({
        fixed: false,
        autoCenter: false,
        scrolling   : 'no',
        beforeLoad : function(){
        var url= $(this.element).attr("data-val");
        this.href = "http://localhost/site/preview/" + url
        },
        type : 'ajax',
        openEffect : 'none',
        closeEffect : 'none',
        padding     : 10
    });
});
```